# MVC 5 User Online with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've started to work with new ASP.Net Identity and I would like to know how does identity handle IsOnline ...? Does it have this option?

And another question using mvc 5 and identity, how do i best keep track of online ppl? Should i still use the old method when user closes the page and then js unload to set the the property in db to IsOnline to false?

But what if user has 2 instances or even 3 instances open of the website and navigates throught different pages, how can i still correctly and synced maintain the online / offline?

Maybe there is some sort of library for that or some new way of doing that? Maybe some helpful link ....

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

By default identity doesn't have anything similar to IsOnline, so you would have to add this functionality yourself.  You can probably do it with a combination of adding a lastActivity property for the user, along with extending UserManager and overriding all the methods you wish to consider the user being online to update this field. Alternatively you could just manually update the lastActivity where appropriate in your app, which might be easier.